# How can I retrieve the text inside a span element having a specific class that is inside a clicked object using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-events

I am not so into JavaScript\jQuery and I have the following doubt about how to handle the following situation in a jQuery script that implements a menu, here the JSFiddle link to see the entire running code:

https://jsfiddle.net/AndreaNobili/s8wos4n2/

So, as you can see in the previous JSFiddle, I have the following situation.

Into the HTML code I have the menu tabs that are implemented by `<li>` tabs something like this:

```
<li class="com__nav-item">
    <a href="" class="com__nav-link centered">
        <span class="blue-line animate scaleIn delay-3 menuVoiceTitle">FUNCTION 1</span>
        <span class="white-circle animate scaleIn delay-5"></span>
    </a>
</li>
```

So, as you can see each `<li>` tab implementing a menu item contain a `<span>` that show the menu item title (for example **FUNCTION 1** in this example).

All these `<span>` have set the `menuVoiceTitle` CSS class.

Ok, when the user click a menu item it is performed the JavaScript `switchTab()` function and here I have the `p` variable:

```
var p = $(this).parent('li');
```

I think that this is the reference of the `<li>` of the clicked link (or something like this).

So now I have the reference of the `<li>` element representing the clicked menu item and now I want to retrieve the text inside the `<span>` element having `menuVoiceTitle` CSS class inside this `<li>` element.

How can I correctly implement this behavior using jQuery?

Comment: is this is a unique class name, why can't you simply use `querySelector` to get the node once you know it's in the DOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Simply:**

```
$('.com__nav-item').click(function(){
   var targettext = $(this).find('span.menuVoiceTitle').text();
   alert(targettext);
});
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jiffiddle/scecoprr/1/)**

Comment: I tryied to integrate into my original JSFiddle but it seems can't work, why?

Comment: Solved by myself, the .click() function have not to be defined on com__nav-item class but on com__nav-link class

Answer (score 0):

```
var p = $(this).parent('li');
```

This line select parent li means current "li tag" you clicked right now.

```
targetText = p.find('.menuVoiceTitle').html();
```

Now, use this line just after "var p = $(this).parent('li');" and you will required text.

Note:-
**find()** is a jquery function which is try to find element by selector (id, class, tag name) inside element.